# Toggle React checkboxes without state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some checkboxes that I'm just using as filters for data that need to run a function on click. Usually, and all tutorials ive read, have suggested to handle checkbox checked attribute using state. Is it possible to do this without using state? I don't really want to declare all the different checkboxes in my state just to toggle them on and off. I was hoping I could do something like this

```
<input type="checkbox" checked={true} onChange={(e) => e.target.checked = false } />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can, using uncontrolled components, then using refs to get the values. It's considered "quick and dirty", but you can do it no problem. See this article for more detailed information: https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html.